# Configure workspace to start applications

Tags: workspaces

How would I go about to create a script which would start a set of applications in a given workspace (ubuntu 11.10)?

Eg. When developing my application X, I use one terminal to run the application, one terminal where I run spec's, one instance of Kate in a specific folder, one instance of Firefox to a specific url and perhaps one instance of a database admin tool loaded with the dev db.

But I do not work on this application everytime I use my computer, so I would like to kickstart a script which would do something like this in a given workspace:

1. Start terminal in folder for X and run all spec's
2. Start new terminal in folder for X and start application
3. Run Kate in folder for X
4. Start firefox with url to X
5. Start db-admin with dev db for X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of two approaches:

1. Install `devilspie` (and optionally the GUI configurator gDevilspie) and use that to determine the workspaces.
2. Make a script or scripts that launch the programs you want started, and put it/them somewhere in your `PATH`.